# Slow research with 'Where-Object' in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I want to retrieve some applications informations, which I can do with the [Get-CMApplication](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj850118(v=sc.20).aspx) cmdlet in PowerShell. But the result can be pretty huge, with many applications which contains a lot of informations.

My issue is that I would like to retrieve only the name of one application. I found how to do it, with this simple line of PowerShell :

```
Get-CMApplication | Where-Object { $_.CI_UniqueID -like ("*" + $line['ApplicationID'] + "*") } | Select-Object LocalizedDisplayName).LocalizedDisplayName
```

The problem is that it is pretty slow. It takes arround 30 seconds and various minutes to return some result, and when I search an application that doesn't exist, it can take up to like 10 minutes, which is way too much. And since this line is actually called in a loop, the script could in theory take several hours to retrieve all the applications name I requested...

I was wondering if there was a fastest way to search in this *Get-CMApplication* result. I already saw the parameters *Id* and *Name* from the *Get-CMApplication* cmdlet, but I am searching for the name and I don't have the Id, only the CI_UniqueID.

Any idea ?

Comment: Have you tried `Get-CMApplication -Id $line['ApplicationID']`?

Comment: Yes I tried this one, but it always return nothing, which means the $line['ApplicationID'] is not a correct -Id value, since I have a result with my current line :/

Comment: In that case I would retrieve all the application once, save them to a variable (possibly in a hashtable for easy lookup) and then use that variable to retrieve the individual application inside the loop

Comment: The problem is that I could ask to search for 1 application or 1000, so if I search 1 application it will be much longer since it will first try to retrieve all the applications in a variable and then search in this variable. Also, why would it be faster if the script search in a variable instead of searching in the table itself ? The only thing I can see is a drawback in terms of memory and space. As I said, it can be a HUGE list...

Comment: That's why I suggested a hashtable for subsequent lookups. In terms of overhead, every time you do `Get-CMApplication | Where-Object {...}` powershell needs to connect to sccm, wait for sccm to execute the query, load all results into memory and process them with Where-Object. Doing it once and then saving only LocalizedDisplayName + ID is likely going to be faster (if slightly more memory consuming)

Comment: I didn't think of the SCCM connexion process and all that stuff. You are totally right about that, I will try to search in that direction. Thanks a lot man.